# Is there a way to apply tailwind classes on react components without restart the server all the time to let each class work?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I have an issue where all the time I add a tailwind class in my react components in order to let the style associated to that class work I need to restart the server, otherwise the style is not applied, even though I can see in the console the class being associated to the component (but not the style itself, which it is not applied at all). The solution is restarting the server.

As soon as I restart the server, or delete the node module and re-install npm, then the style is applied.  While, if I use a class I already used before, it works without restarting the project. I tried to upgrade tailwind but the problem still persists. Any clues?

This is my tailwindconfig file:

```
/* global require */

const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      width: {
        104: '26rem',
        112: '28rem',
        136: '34rem',
        144: '36rem'
      },
      strokeWidth: {
        1.5: '1.5'
      },
      maxWidth: {
        104: '26rem',
        112: '28rem'
      },
      colors: {
        'green': {
          400: '#89ADAA',
          700: '#155C56'
        },
        'gray': {
          500: '#B4B2B1',
          700: '#AFADAC'
        },
        'black': {
          500: '#1E1E1E'
        },
        'black-haze': {
          100: '#F2F4F4',
          300: '#DFE6E8',
          500: '#CDD4DC'
        },
        'desert-storm': '#F4F2F0',
        'spring-green': '#00FA91'
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Roboto', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans]
      },
      transitionProperty: {
        width: 'width'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "customer_app_client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.2",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.22",
    "@types/redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "msw": "^0.39.2",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.15.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "6.2.1",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-toastify": "7.0.4",
    "react-virtual": "^2.10.4",
    "redux": "4.1.0",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start:dev": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.dev.js --port 3006",
    "build:dev": "webpack build --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "build:dev:all": "npm run build:dev && npm run build-storybook",
    "clean:dev": "rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf dist",
    "prettify": "npx prettier --write .",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook --output-dir ../public/storybook"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.9",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.39",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.16.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "5.2.6",
    "cssnano": "5.0.6",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.11.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "fetch-mock": "9.11.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.3.2",
    "http-server": "^14.1.0",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "mdx-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss-loader": "6.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "react-docgen": "^5.4.0",
    "react-docgen-typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "style-loader": "3.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.2",
    "webpack": "5.44.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.7.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.14.0"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "16.14.0"
  },
  "msw": {
    "workerDirectory": "public"
  }
}
```

Comment: I've always used CRA or Vite while you are using a personalized Webpack config (as if you ejected CRA).

Have you tried adding the --watch flag to the webpack server?

Comment: same error persisting

Comment: Is typescript working as expected?